# Removing Specific Folders from a Repo

Tags: git, tfs

I have a repo I have cloned locally from TFS that I am about to push to our new VSTS instance.

Folder structure like so;

```
\A\AA1234\
\A\AA1235\
\A\AA1236\
\A\AAB237\
\A\AAB238\
\A\AAB239\
\B\BA1234\
\B\BA1235\
\B\BAG236\
\B\BAG237\
\B\BAG238\
\C\...
...
```

What I would like is to remove all projects of the format 2 letters followed by numbers and keep the ones with 3 letters followed by numbers (regex below).

I was using the following command which I found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) to remove individual folders;

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r FOLDERTOREMOVE" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

The problem is this doesn't seem to work for subfolders. I could substitute 'FOLDERTOREMOVE' above with 'A' and it would work (I have tested this with a smaller, test repo). But it appears this command only works with top level folders. I have tried the following to no success;

```
AA1234
\AA1234
\A\AA1234
A\AA1234
```

Is there a way to make this command work for subfolders? I can then create a batch file to run for all the folders I would like to remove.

Option 2 would be when it comes to `git push -u origin master`, to somehow specify not to include a folder list/regex.

Option 3, I used git-tfs to clone from TFS. There is an [--ignore-regex](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md) command which I tried (below) but it still seemed to pull down everything. I am willing to rerun the clone if I can get this to only pull the folders I need.

```
git-tfs clone --ignore-regex="\/[a-zA-Z]{1}\/[a-zA-Z]{2}\d" http://tfs:1234/MyTFS "$/MyTFSPath" --branches=none
```

REGEX

```
\\.\\[a-zA-Z]{3}.*?\\
\\.\\[a-zA-Z]{2}[^a-zA-Z].*?\\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't just delete the files locally with cmd command/powershell, then push to VSTS? (why you want to filter the files on the git options?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe I found the issue with the regex not working in my initial clone from TFS. It seems GIT TFS uses a different regex flavour than I was expecting.

While I was using;

```
git-tfs clone --ignore-regex="\/[a-zA-Z]{1}\/[a-zA-Z]{2}\d" http://tfs:1234/MyTFS "$/MyTFSPath" --branches=none
```

This should have actually been;

```
git-tfs clone --ignore-regex="/[a-zA-Z]{1}/[a-zA-Z]{2}\d" http://tfs:1234/MyTFS "$/MyTFSPath" --branches=none
```

Note that the '/' do not need to be escaped with '\' as I had expected. From my tests this regex then works to exclude files/folders you don't wish to include in your clone.